# Two WCF services cannot interact when on same server

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

I have two WCF services hosted with a hosting provider. Both service to work fine. I can access them from my own computer or even from a website hosted with another provider. The weird part (at least, the part I don't understand) is; one cannot call the other.

Both services are located in a subfolder of the web root, at the same hierarchical level. Like wwwroot\serviceone and wwwroot\servicetwo. Both are marked as application folder in IIS en both have an almost similar web.config as shown below, only the names differ:

```
<configuration>
     <system.web>
        <compilation targetFramework="4.0" />
      </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="servone">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="MyService.ServiceOne" behaviorConfiguration="servone">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract=" MyService.IServiceOne "/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>

  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Browsing to the .svc displays the well-known service page with the example code;

```
class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ServiceOne client = new ServiceOne ();
        // Use the 'client' variable to call operations on the service.
        // Always close the client.
        client.Close();
    }
}
```

The client has a method named HandleRequest(string str). So in my code (C#) there's a line like;

```
client.HandleRequest("blah");
```

The call doesn't raise an exception (I can tell because they are catched, handled and written to a database). It's like the message is sent but never returns.
When I run this service (who calls the other) locally and leave the second on the remote server, all works well.

Obvious it is hard to provide all the details from the hosting party. Unfortunate I don't have access to an IIS installation to simulate the environment either. So, I'm not expecting an in-depth technical solution based on the little information I can provide. But any comment about how this setup differs from all others might be helpful.

I really appreciate any effort, thanks.

---

Edit:

The call is made like this:

```
public bool Send(String str)
{
  bool result = false;
  BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
  EndpointAddress ep = new EndpointAddress("http://www.mydomain.com/ServiceTwo.svc");
  client = new ServiceTwoClient(b, ep);
  //
  try
  {
    result = client.HandleRequest(str);
    client.Close();
    return result;
  }
  catch (Exception x)
  {
    Add2DbLog(x.Message);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where service #1 calls service #2?

Comment: Turning on [message logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx) may help you debug this.

Comment: @Keith - Thanks for the suggestion. I'm looking at it right now. Only problem is I'm not allowed to use absolute paths. I updated the post to address your question.

Comment: I highly recommend moving `client.Close()` to a `finally` block to ensure the object is closed even when the service fails. Otherwise the connections are left open and after a while new connections will time out when opening.

Comment: Is it possible that `client.HandleRequest(str)` is throwing an exception but `Add2DbLog` is failing to log it?

Comment: Ow yes, you're right of course. Moved client.Close() already, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain alias you're using may not work locally on the server. Log in to that server, launch a web browser, and navigate to the service URL used in your code (`http://www.mydomain.com/ServiceTwo.svc`). Ensure that you don't get any error messages.

Comment: So, that (domain alias may not work locally) is a possibility indeed? Than that may very well be the case. Hard to check though, I cannot login to the server (cheap account, I know). At the other hand, that's a simple question the hosting provider should be able to answer, right? I'll ask them. I don't know whether they answer their tickets in the weekend, so might take a few days. In the meantime I consider integrating the second service into the first. That should solve this (and maybe some other, yet unknown) problem anyway.  
Thanks a lot Keith.

Comment: It's a possibility. I had it happen once before because of some funny networking configuration. I'm not well versed with networking so I'm not sure what the cause truly is or what the right solution is at the network-level.